# Debian 12 kiosk as readonly

Tags: debian, readonly, kiosk

I have a Debian 12 kiosk. It runs one single flutter app fullscreen with X for ship diagnostic data.

It needs to boot fast (it does in 7secs) and is "shutdown" by power loss regularly.

fsck is disabled because fsck on every boot takes precious time (and its always triggered because of the power loss). This is no good choice because corruption might occur on ext4.

I want to avoid fsck by making the whole system readonly and have maybe a USB drive connected for some persistent bytes.

How do I make Debian 12 readonly?

Comment: May this help you: https://wiki.debian.org/MichaelAblassmeier/CustomLiveCD